# Examples where $f_1\circ f_2 \simeq g_1\circ g_2$ but $f_1\not\simeq g_1$ and $f_2\not\simeq g_2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that composition of homotopic maps is homotopic, but I'm interested in cases where the converse doesn't hold. Like, if $f_2, g_2: Z\to Y$ and $f_1, g_1: Y\to X$, and $X$ is path-connected, and then we let $p,q\in X$ be distinct and then define $f_1, g_1$ are constant maps $f_1(x) = p, g_1(x) = q$. Then, this composition is necessarily homotopic (I think). But, here $f_1(x)\simeq g_1(x)$, but I'm looking for cases where $f_1\not\simeq g_1$ and  $f_2\not\simeq g_2$.

Also, what if all the maps are loops based at the same point. Then, can this ever happen?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the maps $p_1, p_2 : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ defined by $p_1(\theta, \psi) = (\theta, 0)$ and $p_2(\theta, \psi) = (0, \psi)$.  Then $p_1 \circ p_2 = p_2 \circ p_1$ (in fact they are equal) but $p_1 \not\simeq p_2$.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to ask in the part regarding "what if all the maps are loops based at the same point".  In order for that to make sense, I would think that both $Z$ and $Y$ would have to be $[0, 1]$; and then, since $[0, 1]$ is contractible, you would necessarily have to have $f_2 \simeq g_2$.